# Getting sport.failover.FailoverTransport message (INFO) from karaf using ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, talend, karaf

I am using Talend 5.6.2 which has Karaf 2.3.9 and using ActiveMQ (not installed within  Karaf) 5.10.2. 
The problem is for almost every milli second, I get logs as below. How to prevent this log from occuring as it eats up my logspace in no time.

http://pastebin.com/3HcLpNj1

*17:04:24,344 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Task-1  | sport.failover.FailoverTransport 1055 | 262 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.0 | Successfully connected to tcp://172.21.2.45:61616
17:04:24,433 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Task-1  | sport.failover.FailoverTransport 1055 | 262 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.0 | Successfully connected to tcp://172.21.2.45:61616
17:04:24,435 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Task-1  | sport.failover.FailoverTransport 1055 | 262 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.0 | Successfully connected to tcp://172.21.2.45:61616
17:04:24,437 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Task-1  | sport.failover.FailoverTransport 1055 | 262 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.10.0 | Successfully connected to tcp://172.21.2.45:61616*

Comment: Maybe you need to change the logging level to WARN ([see more here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging.html)).

Comment: We tried that, but then for every 10 seconds, we get warn message, informing the failure of this route.
However, was wondering how to prevent this, so that we do not lose the valuable business info that gets logged in INFO

Comment: Reconnects shouldn't be happening that frequently. Would need to see full client uri syntax, broker configuration and/or client code to validate correct setup.